# Variable length sprintf in PHP

Tags: php, function, native

I am trying to make PHP variable length using [sprintf](http://id.php.net/sprintf). Here is the code I use:

```
<?php
echo sprinf ("%*s | %*s | %*s | %*s\r\n%*s | %*s | %*s | %*s\r\n",
6,"Monkey", 7,"Cats", 7,"Giraffe", 6,"Goat",
6,"Goat", 7,"Giraffe", 7,"Cats", 6,"Monkey")
?>
```

Expected:

```
Monkey | Cats    | Giraffe | Goat
Goat   | Giraffe | Cats    | Monkey
```

Result:

```
s | s | s | s
s | s | s | s
```

So, I made my own function:

```
<?php
function _sp($p,$str){
    $pAkhir=$p-strlen($str);
    if($pAkhir<0)$pAkhir=0;
    $pStr=null;for($i=0;$i<$pAkhir;$i++)$pStr.=chr(32);
    return $str.$pStr;
}
?>
```

Thus:

```
<?php
echo sprintf ("%s | %s | %s | %s\r\n%s | %s | %s | %s\r\n",
_sp(6,"Monkey"),_sp(7,"Cats"),_sp(7,"Giraffe"),_sp(6,"Goat"),
_sp(6,"Goat"),_sp("Giraffe"),_sp(7,"Cats"),_sp(6,"Monkey"))
?>
```

Is there a more efficient way, using a native PHP function?

Comment: 1. http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php 2. use `' '` instead of `chr(32)`

Comment: @zerkms: Thank you! It worked! But, why `' '`? `chr(32)` produces a more promising white space.

Comment: "a more promising white space" --- what does this mean?

Comment: Sometimes to a encoding error in the editor that I use, I'm afraid of white space that appear seems weird, as the word `Saté`, `é` change to diamond symbol.

Comment: space is an ascii-safe character. If space is broken in some editor - then the editor is broken. Btw, I see you use `C` letter in `Cats`, not the `chr(xx)`. How `C` is different from space?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. :D Maybe it depends sense of someone.

Comment: If you're worried about the diamond characters, you can always set php's encoding to UTF-8

Comment: @Q. Sheets: what is "php's encoding"?

Comment: @zerkms PHP's (pre 5.4.0) default charset is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @Q. Sheets: so what? I use php 5.2 and I don't experience any issues with utf-8. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not going to argue with you. If you want to learn more, Stack Overflow and PHP.net are wonderful places to explore.

Comment: @Q. Sheets: "If you want to learn more" --- lol. Dude, you don't even realize how wrong you're with your advice. "If you're worried about the diamond characters, you can always set php's encoding to UTF-8" --- the "diamond characters" have nothing to do with php settings. If you think so - you're doing php wrong.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18439/discussion-between-q-sheets-and-zerkms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think answers from @zerkms is appropriate to mean: [str_pad()](http://id.php.net/str_pad). This is more efficient than writing a new function.